# Override Access Permissions from View in Drupal 6

Tags: views, 6, users

I have a `ticket` node that can only be accessed by the creator, or an administrator. I would like to display select fields from the ticket to other users in a view.

The problem is that, since the other users do not have access to the `ticket` node, the entries do not appear in the view.

How can I restrict access to the full ticket, but display selected fields from that ticket in a new view?

Comment: Which Drupal verion ?

Comment: Are you using CCK to define fields ?

Comment: @nikhil Drupal 6

Comment: I am using CCK to define the fields, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I hate dangling answers, I solved this by creating a new content-type and hard coding the query and page content.

The content-type provides the query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) there is a sub module named `content_permissions`, With this you can set role wise permissions for fields

Comment: I created a new role called `affiliate` and allowed viewing of the allowed fields by an affiliate. The fields are still not showing up in the view. Does the node need to have view permission as well? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @JacobGroundwater Full permission for views, have you enabled content_permissions module ?

Comment: Yes I have the content_permissions module enabled. Under `admin/user/permissions` I granted `view field_date` and `view field_amount` (my custom CCK fields) to the `Affiliate` role, however a user under that role still cannot view those fields in my custom view.

Comment: Try giving access all views for all users and check.

Comment: No luck. Perhaps I'm trying to stretch CCK beyond its intended usage.

Comment: May be some miss configuration. I am using it in my D6 site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3141/discussion-between-jacob-groundwater-and-nikhil-mohan)

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/project/views_ignore_node_permissions Drupal 6

> This module allows you to add a filter to views that will completely ignore node permissions. This is useful for displaying info to a user that cannot view the node normally (such as premium content in teaser format)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, here is how to ignore node permissions in a view:

```
Edit Query | Advanced | Other | Query settings | Disable SQL rewriting
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1210272